# Monitor com port with strace

Tags: serial-port, strace

I have written a small application in Java that writes two strings – 'dddd' and 'ffff' – to a com port. I used `strace -s9999 -o serialtrace.log -eread,write,ioctl` to inspect how it writes.

I found that com port descriptor is `5`, but there is a strange line reading information that I don’t write to the com port:

```
Line 112: read(5, "#\n#Tue Jan 14 12:28:06 GMT+01:00 2014\ncurrencyCode=440\nlogFileName=dbg.log\nport=4462\ncommunicationForward=true\nterminalLanguage=4\ntermInterfaces=\ndelLogDaysOld=0\nStopBits=1\nParity=0\nmessagesFileName=language.ini\nDataBits=8\ncomPort=/dev/ttyS0\nInfoInReceiptSlip=1\ntermDataEncoding=1\nBaudRate=9600\nDebugRX=true", 8192) = 311
```

This info is in a configuration file. What is that?

Strace’s filtered output is:

```
Line 112: read(5, "#\n#Tue Jan 14 12:28:06 GMT+01:00 2014\ncurrencyCode=440\nlogFileName=dbg.log\nport=4462\ncommunicationForward=true\nterminalLanguage=4\ntermInterfaces=\ndelLogDaysOld=0\nStopBits=1\nParity=0\nmessagesFileName=language.ini\nDataBits=8\ncomPort=/dev/ttyS0\nInfoInReceiptSlip=1\ntermDataEncoding=1\nBaudRate=9600\nDebugRX=true", 8192) = 311
Line 113: read(5, "", 8192)                       = 0
Line 114: read(5, "", 8192)                       = 0
Line 222: read(5, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0P/\0\0004\0\0\0x4\2\0\0\0\0\0004\0 \0\4\0(\0\34\0\31\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\310\250\0\0\310\250\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\1\0\0\0\310\250\0\0\310\270\0\0\310\270\0\0\34\3\0\0\330\4\0\0\6\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\2\0\0\0\334\250\0\0\334\270\0\0\334\270\0\0\320\0\0\0\320\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0Q\345td\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\305\0\0\0\306\0\0\0i\0\0\0\23\0\0\0{\0\0\0\220\0\0\0\0\0\0\0c\0\0\0l\0\0\0\243\0\0\0~\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\234\0\0\0Z\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\254\0\0\0\212\0\0\0\247\0\0\0\r\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\241\0\0\0\206\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\217\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\263\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\200\0\0\0S\0\0\0009\0\0\0[\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\262\0\0\0U\0\0\0\231\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\270\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\304\0\0\0\235\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\305\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\257\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\223\0\0\0d\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0n\0\0\0\246\0\0\0\0\0\0\0V\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\267\0\0\0\271\0\0\0z\0\0\0\301\0\0\0\27...
Line 232: write(5, "      8643\n", 11)            = 11
Line 233: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 234: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 235: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B115200 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 236: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 237: read(5, "", 1)                          = 0
Line 238: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 239: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B115200 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 240: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 242: write(5, "      8643\n", 11)            = 11
Line 243: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 244: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 245: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 246: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 247: read(5, "", 1)                          = 0
Line 248: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 249: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 250: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 252: write(5, "      8643\n", 11)            = 11
Line 253: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 254: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 255: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 256: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 257: read(5, "", 1)                          = 0
Line 258: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 259: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 260: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 262: read(5, "      8612\n", 11)             = 11
Line 264: write(5, "      8643\n", 11)            = 11
Line 265: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 266: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 267: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 268: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 269: read(5, "", 1)                          = 0
Line 270: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 271: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 272: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 274: write(5, "      8643\n", 11)            = 11
Line 276: write(5, "      8643\n", 11)            = 11
Line 277: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 278: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 279: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 280: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 281: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 282: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 283: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 284: ioctl(5, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
Line 297: write(5, "ddd", 3)                      = 3
Line 305: write(5, "fff", 3)
```

Comment: Next time when you want to find out what file descriptor 5 is for, have a look at /proc/PID/fd/5

Comment: it is a read, so this is sent from the serial port. What device do you have attached there?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a close syscall followed by another open that gets assigned fd 5 before any of the data sent/received from the serial port.

What I believe is happening is that it's reading the configuration file, closing it, then opening the serial port.  Add both open and close to your list of syscalls to trace.

Comment: But how to recognize syscal that opens and closes fd

Comment: They’re named open and close, @vico. :-)